# Gaussian noise: Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, gaussian-noise

As we all know, Gaussian Noise follows Gaussian or Normal distribution, and that distribution follows a $BELL$ $CURVE$.

[image]

As we can see that most of the values are centered around the mean.

Now consider this image

[image]

When I add Gaussian noise to this image I get something like this

[image]

As we can see that the noise appears to be $UNIFORMLY$ $DISTRIBUTED$ throughout the image. There is no region where we can say that the **noises concentrated around the mean value**

So how can these be called Gaussian Noise?

The Code that I have used in octave is given below

```
 pkg load image;

I=imread('C:\Users\Hirak\Desktop\apple.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(I);

J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0.02);
K = medfilt2(J);
imshow(J);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noise is Gaussian noise because the *values* you add to your existing images follow a Gaussian distribution, not the *locations* of where you add the noise - that is uniform (and not random at all - each pixel gets Gaussian noise added to it).

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you meant by "the values you add to your existing images follow a Gaussian distribution"

Comment: Are we adding N random values that are distributed using Gaussian?

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL Yes, where $N$ is the number of pixels.